# Why does Google Search couldn't fetch a sitemap?

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, sitemap, google-search-console

I want to give a better overview about the content of my website to Google cause I noticed that not all URL are crawled by Google automatically. For that I decided to generate a custom sitemap.

I've generated a sitemap for my Nuxt SSR app via [Nuxt-sitemap module](https://sitemap.nuxtjs.org/). And submitted a sitemap to Google Search console.[image: Google Sitemap]

But Google keeps saying that he can't fetch a sitemap, even thru if I click on it - it can access it without any auth or whatsoever.

I've read here that it may be a temp issue and that I have to be a bit patient but it's already like 2 weeks and it keeps saying that it still cannot fetch this sitemap.

I also tried to validate sitemap using some external services and they say that xml is valid[image: validating sitemap]

Here's an example of my XML sitemap (URLs stripped)

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mobile="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-mobile/1.0" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
    <url>
        <loc>url</loc>
        <lastmod>2023-01-29T13:36:18.023Z</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>url</loc>
        <lastmod>2023-01-29T13:36:18.023Z</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>url</loc>
        <lastmod>2023-01-29T13:36:18.023Z</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>url</loc>
        <lastmod>2023-01-29T13:36:18.023Z</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>url</loc>
        <lastmod>2023-01-29T13:36:18.023Z</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>url</loc>
        <lastmod>2023-01-29T13:36:18.023Z</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>url</loc>
        <lastmod>2023-01-29T13:36:18.023Z</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>url</loc>
        <lastmod>2023-01-29T13:36:18.023Z</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>url</loc>
        <lastmod>2023-01-29T13:36:18.023Z</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>url</loc>
        <lastmod>2023-01-29T13:36:18.023Z</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: Have you checked your servers access log? Does it show any requests to that URL about when Google says it checked?

Comment: @joachim I'm working on implementing that feature right now. I'll update you as soon as I will be able to get these logs. I also tried to check GoogleBot hits via Google Analytics but it seems to be not possible to verify that there.
Btw, seems like I'm not the only one experiencing this problem with that Nuxt sitemap module -> https://github.com/nuxt-community/sitemap-module/issues/240#issuecomment-1412119217
Maybe the problem in that?

Comment: it seems that's just a 1 year old problem report and lots of "me too"s. Note that none of the developers provided any useful information (and one user even updated that they had fixed it somehow). So I'm not convinced that there's an actual bug in the code and it's not just a bunch of users that all suffer from some misconfiguration (maybe even the same one).